# How to return mouse coordinates in realtime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I'm new to PyQt and I'm trying to use it to create a widget that returns the position of the mouse in real time.

Here's what I have:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QToolTip, 
    QPushButton, QApplication)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont    

class MouseTracker(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.installEventFilter(self)

    def initUI(self):        
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Mouse Tracker')    
        self.show()

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove and
            event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.NoButton):
                pos = event.pos()
                print('Mouse coords: ( %d : %d )' % (pos.x(), pos.y()))
        return QtGui.QWidget.eventFilter(self, source, event)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MouseTracker()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'm confused on how to make this work. I set mouse tracking to True but I'm not sure how to apply the event filter. Any help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The QMouseEvent function must be implemented since it is executed when the mouse is moved.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QLabel, QWidget)


class MouseTracker(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Mouse Tracker')
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.resize(200, 40)
        self.show()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.label.setText('Mouse coords: ( %d : %d )' % (event.x(), event.y()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MouseTracker()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]