# how to track the mouse over the matplot's canvas in QWidget?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to track the mouse's position over a matplot's canvas in real-time.

For now, I built a MplWidget that inherits the Qwidget (act like a container), then built a canvas over it to show the plot. However, the problem is that I can only track the mouse's position in the padding area except for the canvas area.

Since my canvas inherits the matplotlib.figure that is not a QWidget, thus it doesn't have the setMouseTracking() attribute. In this way, how to resolve this issue?

I found a quite useful link [How to return mouse coordinates in realtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41688668/how-to-return-mouse-coordinates-in-realtime). However, it also suffers the same issue. When the mouse is over the label (text area), the tracking function seems to be interrupted.

my code for this class shown here:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class MplWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure())

        vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        vertical_layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.canvas.axes = self.canvas.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.setLayout(vertical_layout)

        self.setMouseTracking(True)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        text = "x: {0},  y: {1}".format(e.x(), e.y())
        print(text)
        super(MplWidget, self).mouseMoveEvent(e)

    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        print('click!')
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you have noticed the canvas is not handled by Qt but by matplotlib so the solution is to use the events provided by that library, if you review [the docs](https://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html) you see that there are the following events:

> **Event name**    **Class and description**
>
> ```
> 'button_press_event'  MouseEvent - mouse button is pressed
> 'button_release_event'    MouseEvent - mouse button is released
> 'draw_event'  DrawEvent - canvas draw (but before screen update)
> 'key_press_event' KeyEvent - key is pressed
> 'key_release_event'   KeyEvent - key is released
> 'motion_notify_event' MouseEvent - mouse motion
> 'pick_event'  PickEvent - an object in the canvas is selected
> 'resize_event'    ResizeEvent - figure canvas is resized
> 'scroll_event'    MouseEvent - mouse scroll wheel is rolled
> 'figure_enter_event'  LocationEvent - mouse enters a new figure
> 'figure_leave_event'  LocationEvent - mouse leaves a figure
> 'axes_enter_event'    LocationEvent - mouse enters a new axes
> 'axes_leave_event'    LocationEvent - mouse leaves an axes
> ```

In your case you should use the events:

- button_press_event
- button_release_event
- motion_notify_event

Example:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class MplWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MplWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure())

        vertical_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vertical_layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.canvas.axes = self.canvas.figure.add_subplot(111)

        self.canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event", self.on_press)
        self.canvas.mpl_connect("button_release_event", self.on_release)
        self.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", self.on_move)

    def on_press(self, event):
        print("press")
        print("event.xdata", event.xdata)
        print("event.ydata", event.ydata)
        print("event.inaxes", event.inaxes)
        print("x", event.x)
        print("y", event.y)

    def on_release(self, event):
        print("release:")
        print("event.xdata", event.xdata)
        print("event.ydata", event.ydata)
        print("event.inaxes", event.inaxes)
        print("x", event.x)
        print("y", event.y)

    def on_move(self, event):
        print("move")
        print("event.xdata", event.xdata)
        print("event.ydata", event.ydata)
        print("event.inaxes", event.inaxes)
        print("x", event.x)
        print("y", event.y)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MplWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I want! \nI am a newbie for the pyqt5, may I know where I can find the useful and comprehensive doc for pyqt5? Since I found nowhere to look for many small but might be critical stuff, like functions, attributes, etc. Thanks again and sorry for the late response

Comment: @YUNSHENHUANG All the special documentation of PyQt5 is in https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/, but the base documentation is Qt https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/

Comment: Thanks for your help, since my reputation is less than 15, my vote doesn't publicly appear. but I accepted your answer.

Comment: Thank you.
That saved the rest of my day.