# How to access clicked dynamically created matplotlib canvas?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt5

I have 3 QVBoxLayout includes 3 plots each (total 9) in a QHBoxLayout as can be seen here:

[image: here]

I aim to get which canvas is clicked when he/she clicks. I am creating the plots dynamically following:

```
def create_random_figures():
    for i in range(3):
        x, y_leak, y_lin, y_sat = get_points_array(i)
        canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure(figsize=(5, 3)))
        ax = canvas.figure.subplots()
        ax.plot(x, y_leak, '--rs', label='Y_leak')
        ax.plot(x, y_lin, '-g*', label='Y_lin')
        ax.plot(x, y_sat, ':bo', label='Y_sat')
        ax.legend()
```

And connected to a mouse button click event.

```
    canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event", self.canvas_on_press)
    self.vertical_layout_1.addWidget(canvas)
```

In this way, I can get some information (x, y coordinate, etc.) which is clearly explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56283481/how-to-track-the-mouse-over-the-matplots-canvas-in-qwidget) from the clicked canvas but I couldn't find how can learn which canvas is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to detect which canvas was clicked then the best option is to implement logic through inheritance.

```py
class Canvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(Figure(figsize=(5, 3)))
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.mpl_connect("button_press_event", self.on_press)

    def on_press(self, event):
        print(self, event)
```

```py
x, y_leak, y_lin, y_sat = get_points_array(i)
canvas = Canvas()
ax = canvas.figure.subplots()
```

Then it is no longer necessary to identify the canvas since `self` is the canvas.