# How can I show the mouse's coordinates with QGridLayout?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

I'm very new to PyQt5, and I'm trying to display the mouse's coordinates. Eventually I want to only get the coordinates of the mouse when it's on the image, but one step at a time. I've managed to do that, but only when the label giving the coordinates is the only thing there. When I add it to the QGridLayout as a widget, it disappears.

Here's my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap

class Interface(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(50,50,1500,1000)
        self.setWindowTitle('Title')

        self.coords = QLabel(self)

        self.im = QPixmap('image.jpg')
        self.label = QLabel()
        scaled_im = self.im.scaledToHeight(1000)
        self.label.setPixmap(scaled_im)

        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label,1,1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.coords,1,2)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()

    def getCoords(self,event):
        self.coords.setText('Coords: %d' % (event.x(),event.y()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Interface()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Please show us how you got those coordinates when using the label alone, as in your code there's nothing that calls `getCoords()`. Note that grid cell indexes start from 0, not 1.

Comment: I basically used the answer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41688668/how-to-return-mouse-coordinates-in-realtime , but I ended up solving it by calling self.label.mouseMoveEvent = self.getCoords, and changing setMouseTracking to label.setMouseTracking. Thanks for the help about grids too!

Comment: Ok, but for future reference remember to add the relevant code of your attempts to the actual question. Also note that while technically *acceptable*, overwriting event handlers like that is normally discouraged, as it can lead to unexpected behavior and has other indirect issues that can be difficult to work around. Proper solutions are to use an event filter (as in your linked post) or, alternatively, subclass the widget, declare a custom signal, override `mouseMoveEvent()` and emit that signal.